# Java BufferReader To array stored by lines

Tags: java, arrays

Given a list of polynoms I need to store them on different arrays depending on the row.
Example:

**5 -4 2 0 -2 3 0 3 -17** `int[] a = {-17, 3, 0, 3, -2, 0, 2, -4, 5}`

**4 -2 0 1** `int[] b = {1, 0, -2, 4}`

First line I need to put on the array a[], and the second one on array b[]
Tried something like this:

```
File file=new File("Pol.txt");
BufferedReader b=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
Pattern delimiters=Pattern.compile(System.getProperty("line.separator")+"|\\s");
String line=b.readLine();
```

Comment: the order of elements in array is different from what is given in each line.

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: (a) If you don't know what a `Pattern` does, I suggest not using it. (b) Note that you won't be able to call both your array and your buffered reader `b`. (c) I suggest you look through your course materials, and perhaps the documentation of `String`, and try to think of a way to do your assignment. There is no "magic" method that does it all.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will want to make sure that any file reading objects are always properly cleaned up. A [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block is your best bet, or otherwise a try finally block.

```
try(BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream(file))) {
    //code using bufferedReader goes here.
}
```

You should not need to use the `Pattern` class here. It's a simple case of reading a line and using the [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method. e.g.

```
String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
//if (line == null) throw an exception
String[] splitLine = line.split("\\s+");
```

Now the `splitLine` variable will contain an array of Strings, which is each of the elements from the original line, as separated by spaces. The `split` method takes a `String` which is the regular expression representing the 'delimiter' of your values. For more information on regular expressions in Java, try [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum). The `"\\s+"` represents any whitespace character or characters These can be 'parsed' to `int` values using the [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) method, like this:

```
int[] a = new int[splitLine.length];
for(int i = 1; i <= splitLine.length; i++) {
    int parsed = Integer.parseInt(splitLine[i]);
    a[splitLine.length - i] = parsed;
}
```

The `parseInt` method may throw a `NumberFormatException`, for example if you give it the String `"Hello world"`. You can either catch that or let it be thrown.

Comment: More on the `split` method and regular expressions in Java: any String you write in the code (like this `"my string value"`) is read by the compiler in a specific way. Many characters (all letters, numbers, many symbols) mean exactly what you'd expect. However, the `'\'` character has [a special meaning](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html). When we want an actual `'\'`, we simply have to write two. So `"\\s"` is interpreted as `"\s"`. _Then_, in Java regex-speak, this means 'any whitespace character'. The `+` means 'at least one of the preceding'.